# How to display uploaded files dynamically in MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.0

I have a list of files shown on a page:

PDF1,
PDF2,
PDF3,
...

```
 @model IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo>
 @foreach (var file in Model)
 {
     <li class="list-group-item">
         <u>
             <a asp-controller="File" asp-action="DisplayFile">@file.Name</a>
         </u>
     </li>
 }
```

As you can see I use FileInfo class here as a model.

What I would like to achieve that is the file shown in the browser when I click on it's name:

PDF1 click -> shows PDF1

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult DisplayFile()
{
    return new PhysicalFileResult(@"C:\MyProject\UploadedFiles\PDF1.pdf", "application/pdf");
}
```

Two problems I face:

1. This is obviously easy to provide a link to the file, but I want this to be dynamic:

   ```
   return new PhysicalFileResult(dynamically_chosen_file, "application/pdf");
   ```

   So clicking on PDF2 -> shows PDF2, PDF3 -> PDF3, and so on.

   I tried to iterate through the folder and put all files into a list, but still unsure what the next step should be.
2. The PDF shows up in different view - any way to make is displayed in the same view? Read something about using iframes but not too sure how to deal with them.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a query string to your action to select a file based on inputs. Something like this

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult DisplayFile(string filename)
{
    return new PhysicalFileResult(@"C:\MyProject\UploadedFiles\"+filename, "application/pdf");
}
```

Your html file should change to this to send a query string to your action :

```
 @model IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo>
 @foreach (var file in Model)
 {
     <li class="list-group-item">
         <u>
             <a asp-controller="File" asp-action="DisplayFile?filename=@file.Name">@file.Name</a>
         </u>
     </li>
 }
```

For dynamic view try returning `FileStream` instead of `PhysicalFileResult`  like this :

```
public IActionResult DisplayFile(string filename)
{
    var stream = new FileStream(@"C:\MyProject\UploadedFiles\"+filename, FileMode.Open);
    return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/pdf");     
}
```